# How to get the first line using one of the UNIX commands given?

Tags: unix

For the question I can only use `sort`, `uniq`, `cut`, `cat` and `wc`.

I already cut the grades from the text sorted numerically highest grade on the top. I just need to print the highest grade which is in the first line. If I use another command I will lose half of the grade.

Comment: So I guess `head -1` is out of your reach. Sad ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only one of those commands can selectively output particular lines and suppress others.  That command is the one to use.  The question then, is how do you tell it which lines to output?  Check the manpage and see what options it has for controlling the selection of lines.